# Need to restrict decimal to 20

Tags: javascript, locale

I am having a scenario where I convert number into user preference string

```
conv = num.toLocaleString('de-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 20 })
```

As I have real long numbers I want to restrict upto 20 decimal points.
But above code is not giving me desired output.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve same?

Thanks,
Nupur

Comment: What is num? Perhaps it is a string?

Comment: The questions should be asking what browser are you using because according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments) that could be your problem.

Comment: You don't say what your problem is. `(2/3).toLocaleString("de-DE", { maximumFractionDigits: 20 })` prints `0,6666666666666666` in Firefox so I can speculate you're expecting to squeeze more precision that JavaScript is able to provide.

Comment: You should at least provide an example of the number you're putting in, and the output you're expecting. Since double precision float numbers only have 15-17 significant decimal digits, using a value of 20 won't do you any good.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the way that floating point numbers are stored in the processor. See [Floating Point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) and [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

You cannot have 20 significant decimal places in a number. They will get truncated at the end

See an example:
`num = 0.0000000000000000123456;` will show as `"0,00000000000000001235"` and
`num = 1.0000000000000000123456;` will show as `"1,00000000000000000000"`

If you want to force exactly 20 fractional digits use this options object:

`{minimumFractionDigits: 20, maximumFractionDigits: 20}`

Comment: The important part: you can force 20 digits but the last ones will be incorrect (`(2/3).toLocaleString("de-DE", {minimumFractionDigits: 20, maximumFractionDigits: 20})` prints `"0,66666666666666660000"`).